# Flash AS3 class Object calling methods

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

HI all, i have a class file named Main.as and 
another class calledr icon.as

```
package {

    import icon;
    public class main {
        public var _time:String;
        function main() {

            _time="01:10";
            iconObj=new icon(this);

        }
        function timerFunction() {
            _time=newTime;
        }
    }
}

package {

    public class icon {
        public var mytime:NUmber;
        function icon(mainObj:*) {

            trace("My time "+mainObj._time)

        }

    }
}
```

//sample outout

// My time 01:10

How do i get the current update from the main class **without calling the MainObj** repeatedly.
Is this possible in Flash AS3, or any other alternate method for this idea.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). You can have a clock which notifies its observers once the time changes.

Ther are already libraries simplifing this job for you like [as3-signals](http://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals). You can also use [flash.events.EventDispatcher](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html) for the same task.

Comment: actually i dont want to trigger the timer from the main clas. I need to check this from icon.as file. at a specific point i need to get the time from main class.. i think now you understood what i want :)

Comment: If you "need to get the time from main class" you will have to ask for it, like "mainObj.time".

Answer (score 0):

Store a reference to the `Main` class object locally in `Icon`

```
package 
{
    public class Icon 
    {
        public var mytime:NUmber;
        //store an instance of Main obj here.
        public var mainObj:Main;
        public function Icon(mainObj:Main) 
        {
           this.mainObj = mainObj;
        }
        //call this method whenever you want time
        public function readTime():void
        {
           trace("My time " + mainObj._time);
        }
    }
}
```